# How to properly append html into a div, so if the div becomes too large in height, I can scroll its content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to append the html content retrieved
from a url inside a div.

This is my html code:

```
<div id="top-container">
    <div id="views-container">
        <div id="html-container">

        </div>
        <div id="original-page-container">

        </div>
        <div id="result-page-container">

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

and the script to get and paste the page content is:

```
$.get("http://alf.wikia.com/wiki/ALF_Goes_Wild", function(data) {
    $("#original-page-container").append($(data).find(".WikiaMainContentContainer").html());
});
```

this can get and paste the data succesfully inside the div, the problem is that the new html
exceeds the dimentions of the **original-page-container** div and I need that all the retrieved content fits 
the dimensions of the div, if the height is greater, I should be able to scroll the div.

I hope I explained myself clearly.

This is the jfiddle (the script works in my browser with the internet security disabled):
http://fiddle.jshell.net/dc5pQ/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just apply `overflow:auto;` to that `div`.

That way: The scroll will appear only when the data is bigger then the available space.

Notice that a div become scrollable only if he have some `height` or `max-height`, otherwise he will just grow long to fit his content.